# Help installing Wacom Intuos Pen (CTL-480) in Ubuntu Studio 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, wacom

I am very new to Linux terminal work, but that's all that is available when it comes to installing the driver for the Wacom Intuos Pen.

What works: I plug in my Wacom Intuos and the computer recognizes it. I am able to move the cursor via the pen.

What does not work: The art program, GIMP, has difficulty recognizing the tablet at times. At random, it senses the pressure sensitivity, and other times it does not. I am also unable to navigate through internal menus (such as the preferences and save menus) unless I turn off or unplug my tablet and switch to the mouse.

Does anyone know how to install the drivers needed? GUI, terminal, archive, whatever. I just really want to use Ubuntu Studio for what it was developed for instead of working around the [big] kinks.

Comment: ...at least it doesn't crash on you... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1310800 . It works for me in GIMP under 13.10, not tested in 14.04. Have you configured it in GIMP? You need to enable the tablet specifically, see https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/digimend/index.php?title=Tablet_setup_in_GIMP

Comment: I have configured my device in GIMP before. Before, I had it set to "window" but later changed it to "screen". Still, even when I plug it in and turn it on, GIMP does not recognize it. I can use it, yes, but I am unable to use the pressure sensitive features. (I confirmed this by checking under "input devices" in the preferences menu. There are three parts: pad, stylus, and eraser [even though I do not have the eraser hardware feature on my Intuos].)